# Regexp pattern matching IP and UserAgent in an Huge File

Tags: regex

I have a huge log file that has a structure like this:

```
ip=X.X.X.X
userAgent=Firefox
-----
Referer=hxxp://www.bla.org
```

I want to create a custom output like this:
ip:userAgent

for ex:

```
X.X.X.X:Firefox
```

and the pattern will ignore lines which don't start with ip= and userAgent=. (these two must form a pair as i mentioned above.)

I am a newbie administrator and our client needs a sorted file immediately.
Any help will be wonderful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
^ip=(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})[\r\n]+userAgent=(.+)$
```

Apply in global + multiline mode.

Group 1 will contain the IP, group 2 will contain the user agent string.

Edit: The above expression can be simplified a bit, we can remove the IP address format checking - assuming that there will be nothing but real IP addresses in the log file:

```
^ip=(\d+\.?)+[\r\n]+userAgent=(.+)$
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
^ip=((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3})$
```

And

```
^userAgent=(.*)$
```

Get the group 1 for both and you will have the desired data.

Answer (score 0):

give it a try (this is in no way robust if there are lines where your log file differs from the example snippet above):

```
sed -n -e '/^ip=/ {s///
N
s/\nuserAgent=/:/
p 
}' HugeFile > customoutput
```